# How to extract office2003 ppt file with using Tika？

Tags: powerpoint, apache-tika

I have some office2003 .ppt files.In these files there are some embedded files,I want to extract them from ppt file.However,using tika-app-1.16.jar for that only extract some .wmf picture files.So what i should do to extract file from .ppt?

Comment: What options are you passing to Apache Tika?

Comment: -z.I want to extract embedded files in the ppt files which are created by office2003.However,in the HSLFExtractor the HSLFShape cannot get data.

Comment: What do you want - the Text of the PPT file, or all the Embedded Resources of the PPT file? If using the App you need to pass different options for the two!

Comment: I want all the embedded resources of the ppt file.What options do I need to do it?I use "-z file.ppt",but here I encounter two cases.Firstly,I can get resources from .ppt files that are produced by office2016.But if ppts are produced by office 2003,I cannot get them.I debug for that I found that HSLFShape cannot get right dataShape in the HSLFExtractor.